# DB Select within a class in WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I've coded a class which uses connection to the WebMatrix database. I can greatly do insert, update queries, but I have an issue with select queries. 
I can't assign the Razor **dynamic** variable to my type-specified variable.

How to use the WebMatrix database in an usual c# class?

My code from the class:

```
    public bool verify_session()
    {
        if (get_user_id() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["session_id"] != null)
    {
        var db = Database.Open("studia_sesje");
        var data = db.QuerySingle("SELECT session_id, user_id FROM sessions WHERE session_id = '" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["session_id"] + "'");

        _session_id = (string)data.session_id;
        _user_id = (int)data.user_id;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
    }
```

the error is

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the result of your `QuerySingle` method call was null, or no rows in your database were returned. You should check the data is not null before trying to access dynamic properties:

```
var session_id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["session_id"];
var sql = "Select session_id, user_id From Sessions Where session_id = @0";
var data = db.QuerySingle(sql, session_id);
if(data != null){
    _session_id = data.session_id; //bit pointless, you already have that value
    _user_id = data.user_id; // no need to cast to int
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. First check for `null` by

```
var obj=ObjectInfo.ReferenceEquals(Request["cats"],null);
if is obj == true then Execute Query
```